# Program on nested union and structures not working

Tags: c

I am using mingw compiler. This program has been compiled successfully but when executing, the program stops working. Please point out the error and what are the possible debug methods.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
} two;

typedef union
{
 int c;
 float d;
} ad;

typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
 two l;
 ad *n; 
} one;

void trr(one *p);

int main() 
{
 one tr; 
 tr.a=3;
 tr.b=3;
 tr.l.a=5;
 tr.l.b=6;
 tr.n->d=5.43;
 trr(&tr);
 printf("a: %d\nb: %d\nl.a: %d\nl.b: %d\nunion: %f",tr.a,tr.b,tr.l.a,tr.l.b,tr.n->d);
 return 0;
}

void trr(one *p)
{
 p->a=(*p).a+1;
 p->l.a=p->l.a*2;
}
```

Comment: The best debug method in this case would be: read your own code for one minute and tell if it makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
 two l;
 ad *n; 
} one;

....

 tr.n->d=5.43;
```

The `n` member is an uninitialized pointer. You need to allocate memory for it using `malloc()` or assign to it the address of an existing variable.

Compilers can warn you about uninitialized variables if you crank up the warning level.